# Bottleneck in Neural Network for Regression?

Tags: neural-network

I used to use bottleneck layer to limit the degree of freedom in neural network for classification, and I would like to do the same thing for regression. However, this does not seem possible, because I think the bottleneck layer is a bottleneck only when its number of neurons is smaller than that in both the input and output layers, and the output layer of regression always has number of neuron as 1. Can someone tell me if it is possible to achieve the same thing (i.e. limit number of degree of freedom) in classification neural network?